# breeze: many-to-many issues when saving

Tags: breeze

I've been struggling for a while with many-to-many associations in a breeze app. I have issues both on the client and server side but for now, I'll just expose my client-side issue. I don't know if the approach I've come up with is correct or not, and I would really like to get feedback from the breeze team on this:

My business model:

```
public class Request 
{
    public virtual IList<RequestContact> RequestContacts { get; set; }
}

public class RequestContact 
{
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid RequestId { get; set; }
}


public class Contact 
{
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid? ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
}
```

In the success callback of my getRequest query, I add a `contacts` property to the Request and I populate it :

```
request.contacts = [];
request.requestContacts.forEach(function (reqContact) {
    request.contacts.push(reqContact.contact);
});
```

The view is bound to a contacts array, defined in the controller:

```
<select ng-multiple="true" multiple class="multiselect" data-placeholder="Select Contacts" ng-change="updateBreezeContacts()" ng-model="request.contacts" ng-options="c as c.username for c in contacts | filter:{clientId: request.client.id} track by c.id"></select>
```

The controller:

```
//the collection to which the multiselect is bound: 

$scope.contacts = dataService.lookups.contacts;
```

whenever an item is selected or unselected in the multiselect, this method is called:

```
$scope.updateBreezeContacts = function () {
  //wipe out all the RequestContact entities
  $scope.request.requestContacts.forEach(function (req) {
    req.entityAspect.setDeleted();
  });

  //populate the RequestContact based on selected contacts 
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.request.contacts.length; i++) {
     var requestContact = dataService.createRequestContact($scope.request,    $scope.request.contacts[i]);
     $scope.request.requestContacts.push(requestContact);
  }
```

where the createRequestContact method of the dataService actually does that:

```
manager.createEntity('RequestContact', { request: myRequest, contact: myContact});
```

Use case scenario:

---

- The request has one selected contact.
- User unselect the contact and then select another one from the list.
- Then she decides to reselect the one that was previously unselected. We now have two selected contacts.
- User hits the save button and the call to saveChanges is made. Breeze sends 3 entities to the server: the first contact with 'Deleted' status, the same contact again with 'Added' status, and finally the other contact that was selected, also with 'Added' status.

---

Is this what should be done when working with many-to-many associations ?

I actually get a server error ("not-null property references a null or transient value Business.Entities.RequestContact.Request") but before I draw any conclusions, I'd like to know if what I do on the client-side is correct.

Comment: Where are the PKs for the C# `Request` and `Contact` classes (e.g., `Request.Id` and `Contact.Id`)?

Comment: I've omitted them in the SO post, but they are in my code. Sorry for the lack of accuracy in my model description. And thanks so much for the long answer, I just saw it so give me some time to process it before I reply :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Server-side

You have server-side modeling problems to deal with first. I noted the absence of PKs in my comment to your question. I suggest that you get that working first, before bothering with the client.

## Client-side

I have long experience with this kind of scenario. For me the canonical case is a User who can have any number of Roles and the roles s/he has are in the UserRoles table.

The typical UI:

- select and present a User
- present a list of all possible roles for that user with a preceding checkbox
- the checkbox is checked if the user has that role; unchecked if s/he does not

### Uh Oh

Many times I have seen people bind the list of all possible roles to a list of `UserRole` *entities*. This rarely works.

Many time I have seen people create and destroy `UserRole` *entities* as the user clicks the checkbox. This rarely works.

Too often I have seen `UserRole` *entities* added and deleted and added and deleted to the cache. This is usually fatal as the client loses track of whether a `UserRole` entity does or does not correspond at this moment to a record in the database.

If I read your code correctly, you are making everyone of these mistakes.

### Item ViewModel instead

I have had more success when I represented this user's roles as a list of **"Item ViewModel" instances** and postponed entity manipulation until it was time to save the user's selections.

For our discussion, let's call this object a **UserRoleVm**. It might be defined as follows in JavaScript

```
{
    role,
    isSelected,
    userRole
}
```

When you build the screen,

- populate a list of `UserRoleVm` instances, one for every `Role`
- set each vm's `role` property with the appropriate `Role` entity
- bind the view to `vm.role.name`
- set each vm's `userRole` property with the pertinent user's `UserRole` entity *if and only if such an entity already exists*
- set vm's `isSelected=true` if the vm has a `userRole` and if `vm.userRole.entityAspect.entityState` is not Deleted.
- bind the vm's `isSelected` to the checkbox

Now the user can check and uncheck at will.

I do not create/delete/modify any `UserRole` entity while this is going on. I wait for the UI signal to save (whatever that signal happens to be).

During the Save preparation, I iterate over the list of `UserRoleVm` instances

- if not checked and no `vm.userRole`, do nothing
- if not checked and have `vm.userRole`, then `vm.userRole.entityAspect.setDeleted()`. If `vm.userRole.entityAspect.entityState` is Detached (meaning it was previously in the Added state), set `vm.userRole` = null.
- if checked and no `vm.userRole`, create a new `UserRole` and assign it to `vm.userRole`
- if checked and have `vm.userRole`, then if `vm.userRole.entityAspect.entityState` is

  - Unchanged, do nothing
  - Modified (why? how?),  revert by calling `vm.userRole.entityAspect.rejectChanges()`
  - Deleted (must have been a pre-existing `UserRole` that was "unchecked" but still not saved; how did that happen?), revert by calling `vm.userRole.entityAspect.rejectChanges()`

Now call `manager.saveChanges()`.

- If the save succeeds, all is well.
- If it fails, the cleanest approach is call `manager.rejectChanges()`. This clears the decks (and discards whatever changes the user made since the last save).
- Either way, rebuild the list from scratch as we did at the beginning.

Ideally you do not let the user make more changes to user roles until the async save returns either successfully or not.

I'm sure you can be more clever than this. But this approach is robust.

**Variation**
Don't bother with `UserRoleVm.userRole`. Don't carry the existing `UserRole` entity in the `UserRoleVm`. Instead, refer to the user's cached `UserRole` entities while initializing the `UserRoleVm.isSelected` property. Then evaluate the list during save preparation, finding and adjusting the cached `UserRole` instances according to the same logic.

#### Enabling the Save button (update 19 Dec)

Sam asks:

> The Save button's disabled attribute is bound to a property set to true when the EntityManager has changes. However, since my ViewModel is NOT part of the EntityManager, when the user adds/removes contacts, that does not change the Model attached to the EntityManager. Therefore the Save button is never enabled (unless I change another property of the model). Can you think of a workaround for that?

Yes, I can think of several.

1. Define the `isSelected` property as an ES5 property with get and set methods; inside the set method you signal to the *outer* VM that the `UserRoleVm` instance has changed. This is possible because you must be using an ES5 browser if you've got Angular and Breeze working together.
2. Add an ngClick (or ngChanged) to the checkbox html that binds to a function in the *outer* vm, e.g.,

   ```
   <li ng-repeat="role in vm.userRoles">
       ...
       <input type="checkbox" 
              ng-model="role.isSelected" 
              ng-click="vm.userRoleClicked(role)"</input>
    ...
   </li>
   ```
3. Leverage angular's native support for "view changed" detection ("isPristine" I think). I don't usually go this way so I don't know details. It's viable as long as you don't allow the user to leave this screen and come back expecting that unsaved changes to the `UserRoleVm` list have been preserved.

The `vm.userRoleClicked` could set a `vm.hasChanges` property to true. Bind the save button's isEnabled is to `vm.hasChanges`. Now the save button lights up when the user clicks a checkbox.

As described earlier, the save button click action iterates over the `userRoleVm` list, creating and deleting `UserRole` *entities*. Of course these actions are detected by the `EntityManager`.

You could get fancier. Your `UserRoleVm` type could record its original selected state when created (`userRoleVm.isSelectedOriginal`) and your `vm.userRoleClicked` method could evaluate the entire list to see if any current selected states differ from their original selected states ... and set the `vm.hasChanges` accordingly. It all depends on your UX needs.

> Don't forget to clear `vm.hasChanges` whenever you rebuild the list.

I think I prefer #2; it seems both easiest and clearest to me.

## Update 3 February 2014: an example in plunker

I've written [a plunker to demonstrate the many-to-many checkbox technique](http://plnkr.co/edit/G4gOH68iKLobAumoEsXx) I described here. The *readme.md* explains all.

Comment: Thanks Ward. Regarding method 2, may I ask what the userRoleClicked function is supposed to do ? I don't really get it. More specifically, how do you tell breeze that the EntityManager should be dirty ? Alternatively, method 3 could be an option for me.

Comment: Updated the update in an attempt to clarify the behavior of `userRoleClicked`

Comment: OK, it makes perfect sense now ! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Oh and instead of manager.rejectChanges(), I've used  manager.getChanges('RequestContact') and then looped through entities in order to rejectChanges on each one. Otherwise, the whole form would get reset, which is not convenient for the user.

Answer (score 1):

The Breeze.js client does not support "many to many" relationships at this time. You will have to expose the junction/mapping table as an entity. There are several other posts on this same topic available.

We do plan to add many-many support in the future. Sorry, but no date yet...

Comment: I know that many-to-many is not yet supported. I have exposed the junction table as described in my post. That's why I have put together this code in order to create RequestContact entities based on the selected Contact(s). But I'm not sure this approach is correct, and therefore I'm unable to tell whether the server error I'm getting is related to this code or to something else.

Comment: Ward, I have another question regarding your solution. In the case the Save fails, you said the cleanest way is to call manager.rejectChanges(). But that is not something I want to do because there are other fields in my form, and they certainly shouldn't be reset to original values, that would piss off my users for sure :) What I want, is to only revert changes made to the RequestContacts collection (UserRoles collection in your case). I have no idea how to do that though. Any idea ?