# Managing many-to-many relationship with Breeze

Tags: many-to-many, breeze

I know that it cannot yet. But having many-to-many is a common thing in my opinion and I would like to ask some suggestions or opinions about the method I follow.

I work on a blog engine where the user can create blog entries and she/he can add multiple tags to it. There are Blog_Entry, Tag and a Blog_Entry_Tag tables. The Blog_Entry table has navigation property to Blog_Entry_Tag table. The Tag table also has navigation property to Blog_Entry_Tag table. Both are one-to many relation. Between Tag and Blog_Entry tables there is no any navigation property. The joining table exposed to Breeze.

When creating and editing new entry the blog entry related data managed separately from the tag related data. At saving I have to manage that the proper data will be inserted into the Blog_Entry_Tag table. The save logic is complicated but managable however, I can't leverage on Breeze great capabilities.

How do you manage situation like this? I know the question might be general, but I went through the available documentation and whatever was displayed in Google without getting closer to the solution or getting even smarter. If you have blogs, examples about this case I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these two documents, hopefully one of these may offer some help.

http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/presenting-many-many

[breeze: many-to-many issues when saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638851/breeze-many-to-many-issues-when-saving)

Comment: Thanks, they helped a lot, especially how Ward described step by step what to do and why it worth to do so! I did what was suggested by him. I separated the atomic steps and I work with entities only when I'm saving them. However, I'm looking forward to have the many-to-many capabilities of Breeze, but having the experience it is much easier to manage situations like I described above.